# Dynamically Fittext a cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, ole

I'm creating a Table in Word using OLE automation in perl. I'm populating the table contents programmatically. The row height and column width are specified. I'm trying to achieve the following.

In cases where the cell contents are larger than the width of the cell, I would like to set the FitText property so that the row height is unchanged. However, I'm unable to identify the cells where this would be the case. Setting the Fittext property to be True for all  the cells, streches the contents of the cells which are smaller than the width of the cell. So, I prefer to set the FitText property to be True for cell contents that are wider than the cell.

I tried the following

```
# set row height
$rowheight=20; 
...
...
$table1->Cell($rowindex,$colindex)->{WordWrap}="True";
$table1->Cell($rowindex,$colindex)->Range->{Text}=$text;
$cellheight = $table1->Rows($rowindex)->{Height};
if ($cellheight > $rowheight){
$table1->Cell($rowindex,$colindex)->{FitText}="True";
}
```

However, cell height property does not change since the heightrule is set to wdRowHeightAtLeast and the cellheight that is returned is unchanged from the original rowheight.

I also see this behaviour manually in word. When wordwrap is turnedon and cell contents are bigger, the corresponding row gets bigger.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this?

Thank you
SR

Answer (score 0):

### You might be thinking of `AutoFit`, not `FitText`.

From: **FitText (MSDN)**

> If the FitText property is set to `True`, the font size of the text is not changed, but the visual width of the characters is adjusted to fit all the typed text into the cell. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/cell-fittext-property-word))

From: **Table.AutoFitBehavior Method (MSDN)**

> Determines how Microsoft Word resizes a table when the AutoFit feature is used. ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/table-autofitbehavior-method-word))

You should have more luck with `AutoFit` and it's related methods.

But *beware*, if you're not very familiar with manipulating Word Objects with VBA, it's not going to be easy.

> Controlling tables is rather complicated. Word does much of it the way it sees fit, but if you use VBA you must take control. It really isn't desirable that you should make your life even more miserable by invoking the Selection object.

See [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781870/using-vba-in-word-2010-to-change-column-widths-in-a-table) and also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42222820/8112776) for more info.